# Using firebase cloud messaging in a device without Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm developing an app that will run in a android device that doesn't have google Play Store, and Google Play services. 
I need to use the firebase CM in my app. Is there any way to include the plugin inside my APK (is not going to be distributed outside those devices) so the service works properly?

Comment: i don't think FCM or GCM will work on non google play services devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet, there is no official or announced support for using Firebase without Google Play.. Some Firebase dependencies like Realtime database may work but not recommended from Firebase